# Android GPS Tracking application

Tags: android, gps

I'm creating an application that start tracking when a toggleButton is clicked, and stops when the toggle button is recliked, i want just to know if it's a good idea to do the tracking separatly in a service, is there something that I should know,
BTW I've created a service that gives the current location to which I want to add the fonctionallity of tracking.
Thanks for help!

Comment: Check out the [github project](https://github.com/NeilSayok/Car-Locator-System). This project tracks car but is same of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying the new FusedLocationProvider in the Google play services .. it provides a pretty decent performance and accuracy .. without you having to worry about all the details